# bottleneck running task.run on asp net mvc

Tags: async-await, task

I have doubts regarding The legacy ASP.NET Synchronization-Context, 
    If I run the following methods in an ASP.Net MVC Application:

```
   `Task.Run(async () => await httpClient.getContentAsync()).Result 
    var response= Task.Run(() => methodAsync(model));
    var other = response.Result 
    var response= await  Task.Run(() => methodAsync(model));`
```

those calls can generate a bottleneck?

```
all this in an mvc application that is not .net core
```

Comment: `HttpClient.GetContentAsync` is already asynchronous, there's no need for `Task.Run`. `.Result` is a blocking call which means any benefit you get from asynchronous operation goes away and yes, you can cause bottlenecks. Remove *all* of this code and only leave `var content=await httpClient.GetContentAsync();`. ASP.NET MVC provides asynchronous actions since MVC4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [should not use `Task.Run` in ASP.NET at all (classic *or* core)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). You also shouldn't be using `Result` to block on asynchronous code; that *can* [cause a deadlock with ASP.NET Classic](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

For `async` code, just use plain `async` and `await`:

```
var result = await httpClient.getContentAsync();
var other = await methodAsync(model);
```

Comment: thanks stephen , for answering my question
I understand that I should not do that, I have inherited an application and I want to support or prove in what situations a bottleneck could generate a call with task.run, I did a test project and the method responds and that does not help in my goal of prove that it is bad practice.

Comment: @developer: It will *work* - in the sense that it will still return a response. But that approach puts more pressure on the thread pool. So you'll only see a real difference when the system is under load.

Comment: I was thinking about using jmeter and reshaper but I do not know how to interpret the results of dotcover reshaper and what heavy work is. You have an article on how to interpret those results.

Comment: @developer: No, I do not, sorry.

Comment: thanks stephen, only theory will remain the problem that can cause the use of task.run given the misuse of resources (threads). I read some of your articles where you mentioned that asp net core does not exist in context. task.run therefore did not generate a bottleneck, that's where my doubt came from. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html